# Replacing protocol and hostname in URL in Go

Tags: string, go, url, url-rewriting, substring

Is there a straightforward way in Go to modify a URL/URI without having to use regex to extract the components (i.e. I'm looking for a deterministic "tried and true" way/approach).

For example, I have two types of URLs that get sent to my application:

- `http://wiley.coyote.acme.co/this/is/a/long/path?param1=123&param2=456`
- `https://road.runner.acme.co/another/long/path?meep=meep`

What I need to do is re-write the URLs so the parameter list and endpoint/path is intact, but the protocol is changed from `http` to `https` (unless it's already `https`), and the entire hostname/FQDN needs to be changed to `egghead.local`. So, for example, the two URLs above would become:

- `https://egghead.local/this/is/a/long/path?param1=123&param2=456`
- `https://egghead.local/another/long/path?meep=meep`

Is there a reliably/mature approach to handling this (e.g. preferably without regex)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`url`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/) package:

```golang
func toHTTPS(addr string) (string, error) {
    u, err := url.Parse(addr)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    u.Scheme = "https"
    return u.String(), nil
}
```

or

```golang
func setHostname(addr, hostname string) (string, error) {
    u, err := url.Parse(addr)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    u.Host = hostname
    return u.String(), nil
}
```